# one Jenkins server with several gerrit servers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I need a solution for handle one Jenkins server connecting to several Gerrit servers.
As far as I know, the Gerrit plugin in Jenkins can only fillin one URL. 
Anyone knows if it is possilbe to config one plugin for several gerrit servers? or I need to install several plugins (if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the gerrit-trigger plugin for Jenkins can only attach to one Gerrit server at this time.  The developers have indicated they are open to contributions which would enhance the plugin to support multiple Gerrit servers, but nobody has done the work for this yet.

There is no way to load several copies of a plugin in Jenkins.  Your only option at this time is to set up at least one Jenkins server per Gerrit server.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Gerrit server support since Version 2.11.0-beta-1 (released Nov 26 2013)